# When returning a json, how can you tell using Spring that you want to go to a certain url?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my code, I am returning a path in String form(/successPassword or /systemError). Basically this tells Spring to go to the path /successPassword or /systemError, /successPassword goes to successPassword.html and /systemError goes to systemError.html. These html files are located in src/main/resources/templates.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/new_password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createNewPassword(@RequestParam(value = "newpassword", required = false) String password,
        @RequestParam(value = "hash") String hash, Model model) {

    LOG.info("set new password using hash " + hash);
    LOG.info("new password " + password);

    boolean hashValid = passwordService.isHashValid(hash);

    if (hashValid) {
        ValidateMessage message = passwordService.validateNewPassword(password);
        if (!message.isError()) {
            Account account = passwordService.getAccount(hash);
            passwordResetService.saveNewPassword(password, account);
            model.addAttribute("account", account);
            return "/successPassword";
        } else {
            LOG.info("Password not complex enough.");
            return "/systemError";
        }
    } else {
        LOG.info("Invalid hash.");
        return "/systemError";
    }
}
```

Now it looks like I need to return a json object instead. I know that I have to annotate the method with @ResponseBody instead, but my question is how would i package now the object that I will return so that whoever receives it will know to which path it needs to go to? My html codes are using Thymeleaf (no javascript whatsoever).

Comment: Is ModelAndView an option for you? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc

Comment: Is ModelAndView the only way to go?

Comment: Alternatively, you can develop pure @RestController s and consume those resources in your view components